# How to create Javascript Class Method and Class Consts?

Tags: javascript

What I want to establish is like:
    a class Log, which has a global variable _level, indicating the current log level.
    a function log(level, msg), which compare the level with _level, and decide whether print the msg.

the usage is like:

```
Log.SetLevel(1);  //global level
var logger1 = new Log();
logger1.log(0, "should print");
logger1.log(2, "should not print");
```

But I just can't get it done, seems my understanding of Javascript object model has some problems, could anyone please attach a simple code ?

Comment: Would you, please, provide a `Log` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function Log() {}
Log._level = Infinity; // Log all messages by default

Log.SetLevel = function (level) {
  Log._level = level;
};

Log.prototype = {
  log: function (level, message) {
    if (level <= Log._level) {
      console.log(message);
    }
  }
};
```

Demo:

```
var logger1 = new Log();

logger1.log(0, "should print");
logger1.log(1, "should print");
logger1.log(2, "should print");

Log.SetLevel(1);  //global level

logger1.log(0, "should print");
logger1.log(1, "should print");
logger1.log(2, "should not print");
```

Comment: The OP wants a 'global variable' called _level. Here, _level is not a global variable. Its rather a local variable to the Log function.

Comment: It is effectively global.  The use of true globals is a very bad practice.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny he doesn't want that, he just didn't explain it well

Comment: @DylonEdwards, I've tried, and in my firefox : "TypeError: Log.setLvel is not a function"

Comment: @Jerrylk A typo perhaps. Its Log.SetLevel not Log.setLvel. Also, note that JavaScript is case sensitive. So setLevel() and SetLevel() are treated as different functions

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny, my mistake, it works now. but why the "logger1._level" is undefined but the "Log._level" is correctly set. I think logger1's prototype is Log now and it could get _level from Log?

Comment: Log._level is an attribute associated explicitly with the Log function, not its instances.  In JavaScript, symbols are resolved by iterating up the prototype hierarchy of an object (like a tree); attaching _level to the Log function, directly, associates the symbol with a leaf node that lies outside of the path between the root prototype and the instances of Log, which is why logger1._level does not resolve to a value.

Comment: If you want different instances of Log to have different levels, then you should move SetLevel to the prototype of Log, and use this._level instead of Log._level.

If instead you want a singleton logger, then consider this pattern:

var logger = {_level: Infinity, SetLevel: function (level) { this._level = level; }, log: function (level, message) { if (level <= this._level) { console.log(message); }}};

Comment: @DylonEdwards, so in a simple explain is that: the logger share the variable from the prototype of Log rather than Log itself?

Comment: Yes.  Instances can only reference values in themselves and their constructor functions' prototypes.  Prototypes are instances too, so they can access their own values and the values of their constructor functions' prototypes.  They cannot, however, reference values associated explicitly with their constructor functions.  This example may help: http://pastebin.com/pD9Acz1d

Comment: An instance cannot directly modify the values of its constructor's prototype.  When you modify a value of an instance, a new value with the given name is bound to that instance and the value in the prototype is left alone.  You can, however, modify the value of a prototype (directly) after instances have been created. If you've explicitly modified the value in one of the constructor's instances, it will be left alone; otherwise the value will reflect the prototype's: http://pastebin.com/UvPA25cU

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have **"classes"**, but, you could create a constructor and do it like so

```
// create constructor
function Log() {}

// "global" Log level
Log.prototype.level = 0;

// Logger method
Log.prototype.log = function (level, message) {
    return level === this.level ? alert(message) : false;
};

// change level method
Log.prototype.setLevel = function(level) {
    // change level on constructor prototype
    return this.constructor.prototype.level = level;
};
```

This would be a correct way to accomplish this

```
var logger = new Log;
logger.setLevel(1)
logger.log(1, "should print");
logger.log(2, "should not print");
```

This way you can actually access level as well, you shouldn't hide things unnecessarily

Comment: @RobG I did just remove it, now it's back there again, thanks

Comment: @RobG it wasn't until after that I realised it wasn't needed.

Comment: @Connor Thanks! currently it works as I want except that I have to set the log level through a Log instance "logger", not the Log "class", it's a little strange.  What I don't understand is that why I need to insert "constructor", I've tried to directly set the variable and functions to Log.prototype, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jerrylk you can change it to `Log.prototype.level`, but the reason i done `constructor` is because then you can rename `Log` and it won't break, and it's not strange, it is global to the constructor theoretically, it changes for every single instance

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following, which keeps the "global" *level* in a closure and provides priviliged functions to access it.

```
// Initialise the constructor
var Log = (function() {

  // Keep level private in a closure
  var _level = 0;

  // Actual constructor function (it can be called anything)
  function Log(){

    /* constructor code here */

  }

  // Priviliged method to set the value of level
  Log.setLevel = function(level) {
    _level = level;
  }

  // Priviliged method to get the value of level
  Log.getLevel = function() {
    return _level;
  }

  // Assign Log to global variable Log
  return Log;
}());

// Method inherited by all instances of Log
Log.prototype.log = function(level, msg) {
  if (level <= Log.getLevel()) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

// Create some instances
var logger0 = new Log();
var logger1 = new Log();

// Set the level
Log.setLevel(1);

// Do some logging
logger0.log(1, 'should print 0');     // prints
logger0.log(2, 'should not print 0'); // doesn't print
logger1.log(1, 'should print 1');     // prints
logger1.log(2, 'should not print 1'); // doesn't print

console.log(Log.getLevel()); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks, could please compare your solution to Dylon Edwards' solution? I think most of them are the same, except you use a anonymous function, what would be different?

Comment: Dylon's answer has a public *_level* rather than private, and needlessly replaces *Log.prototype*.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your code as this:

```
var logLevel = 1;

function Log() {
    this.log = function (level, msg) {
        if (level === logLevel) {
            alert(msg);
        }
        else {
           //Whatever you want to do
        }
    };
}

var logger1 = new Log();
logger1.log(1, "should print");    //will alert
logger1.log(2, "should not print");    //will not alert
alert(logLevel);        //to prove that 'logLevel' is defined at a global level. The value is alerted signifying its scope to be at the global level
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/4f34c/1/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but the logLevel is now a global variable, which may cause problems in the future.